# Authenticating NodeJS with Axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I have a closed CouchDB application (so it requires authentication).
I'm connecting to it from a NodeJS backend which has to get admin access and do its thing. So I want to intercept requests that are not authenticated or expired.

To do that, I've `axios.create()`d a `client`. That client has an interceptor which uses the original `axios` object to authenticate, then sets the cookie from the response to the `client`'s default headers. The code looks a bit like this:

```js
import axios from 'axios';

const baseURL = 'http://127.0.0.1:5984/';
const name = 'admin';
const password = 'mypass';
const cookieTimeout = (10 * 60 * 1000);
let cookieCreated;

const client = axios.create({
    baseURL,
    headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        post: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
    },
});

const cookieInterceptor = (config) => {
    const now = Date.now();
    if (!cookieCreated || cookieCreated + cookieTimeout <= now) {
        // Using the default 'axios' object because if we use 'client',
        // it will loop into intercepting its own request again.
        return axios.post(`${baseURL}/_session`, { name, password })
            .then((response) => {
                // Cache a new cookie and return it
                cookieCreated = now;
                client.defaults.headers.common.Cookie = response.headers['set-cookie'].join(';');
                return config;
            })
            .catch(error => console.log(error));
    }

    return Promise.resolve(config);
};

client.interceptors.request.use(cookieInterceptor);

export default client;
```

This is probably a sub-optimal way of doing it, but the actual issue is that calling `client.get()` doesn't end up being an authenticated request when I'm calling it for the first time after launching the app. It's good afterwards though so it's probably that the authentication process goes somewhere in the background.

Question is, how do I make my interceptor authenticate my client before making the actual request? Is an interceptor the right way of doing it? Also, if there's a less horrible way to go about this, I'm fully open to suggestions.

Comment: I * think * it should be axios namespace instead of instance: `client.interceptors.request.use` => `axios.interceptors.request.use`

Comment: Nono, the `client` is what's exposed to the rest of the system. The `axios` object is only used by the client so it doesn't enter an endless loop where it would intercept its own requests.

Comment: Nevermind.. ;) at least your shown code seems to work, take a look here: https://repl.it/repls/DeepskyblueStraightActivecontent